# vim: FuzzyFinder and the numbers of the list of the matching file names

Tags: vim

I'm using FuzzyFinder, when I start to write the name of a file to open it, a list of files that match the letters are shown. On the left of each of those files there is a number.

What do those number mean? Is there maybe any way to open a file from the list using that number?

Or what way do you use for selecting the files from the list apart from using the cursor keys?

Javi

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation (`:help fuzzyfinder`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those numbers can be used if you append it after a `;` - so if you type `ab` and end up with a list with 10 files, you can select the 5th with `ab;5`.

You could also select a file from the list without entering a pattern at all, starting directly with `;` and following with a number in the list. More info at `:h fuf-search-patterns`.

I use <kbd>Ctrl-p</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl-n</kbd> to select the match, similar to cursor keys, when the desired file is at most three or four positions from the top.